# Trouble updating context value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the react `useContext` hook and trying to update its value.

Context as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

const TokenContext = React.createContext({
    token: null,
    setToken: () => {}
});

export default TokenContext;
```

and `NotFound.js`

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import TokenContext from '../../contexts/TokenContext';

const NotFound = () => {
    const { token, setToken } = useContext(TokenContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        setToken('3');
    });

    return (
        <h1 className="heading-text font-weight-bold text-center">
            404 Not Found
        </h1>
    );
};

export default NotFound;
```

I am getting the error `(anonymous function)` when trying to call `setToken`, how can I fix this?

Comment: Please show the provider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context consumers (components calling `useContext`/`Context.Consumer`) must be children of `Context.Provider`.

> When React renders a component that subscribes to this Context object it will read the current context value from the closest matching Provider above it in the tree - [source](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext).

Also, giving an initial function like `setToken` won't trigger a render because such function is not a part of React API.

```
const TokenContext = React.createContext({
  token: null,
  // Won't trigger render, is just a regular function
  // Not part of React API
  setToken: () => {}
});

const NotFound = () => {
  const { token, setToken } = useContext(TokenContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setToken(3);
  }, [setToken]);

  return <h1>{token}</h1>;
};

// Use provider to pass values and setters
const ContextProvider = () => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  return (
    <TokenContext.Provider value={{ token, setToken }}>
      <NotFound />
    </TokenContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit confident-sammet-7w2w1]

Comment: I forgot to add it to my question by my main App is wrapped in context provider and I still get that error.

Comment: @Kex you have a codesandbox attached, try to replicate the behavior and show your full code

Comment: Thank you this is working now and I understand it. One question though. You are passing the setToken function directly as a prop to provider. Is this safe?

I remember seeing that for class based components `setState` should not be passed as a prop but instead a function passed that mutates it. Is this different for functional components and hooks?

Comment: It is safe, https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate, read the note, the function is stable across all renders.

Comment: Awesome, that makes things much cleaner! Thanks